# Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I'm learning Swift and following some tutorials. I keep getting an error:
Type

> 'ViewController' does not conform with protocol
>   'UITableViewDataSource'

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var GetAllDataTest  = NSMutableArray()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        GetAllDataTest = FMDBDatabaseModel.getInstance().GetAllData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestTableViewCell") as! TestTableViewCell
        //cell.editData = self
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        var l = Tbl_Test()
        l = GetAllDataTest.object(at: indexPath.row) as! Tbl_Test

        cell.lblName.text! = l.Name
        cell.lblMobileNo.text! = l.MobileNo
        cell.lblEmail.text! = l.Email

        return cell
    }
}
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. I have ensured the function is inside the Class.
2. I have ensured theViewController outlets are the main story board.
3. Read other StackOverflow questions with similar issues, no solution I can find. (I could have missed it).

Thanks

Comment: you are missing numberOfRows.

Comment: Both methods are mandatory to UITableViewDataSource protocol cellForRow and numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: A hint to help yourself: In the Issue Navigator click on the disclosure triangle next to the error message and read which methods are missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement other methods as well. Here you are missing

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    return GetAllDataTest.count
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats perfect!